# How to use Session.setDefault() with external data inside helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

I use **Meteor 1.2.1**. I am currently developing a Course Catalog Web App.
I'm trying to create a filtering feature just like [Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). It should let the user specify his needs and then the course list refreshes automatically as he changes the filters.

This is my code:

**app.html**

```
<!-- ********** -->
<!-- courseList -->
<!-- ********** -->
<template name="courseList">
  <div class="list-header">
    <div>Course Name</div>
    <div>Description</div>
    <div>Category</div>
    <div>Modality</div>
    <div>Unit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-body">
    {{ #each course }}
      {{ > courseRow}}
      <hr />
    {{ /each }}
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
  Template.courseList.helpers({
    'course': function(){
      Session.setDefault('course', Courses.find().fetch());
      return Session.get('course');
    }
  });
```

So when I run this, I get an empty set for the `course helper` above, even though there's some dummy data present on the database.

It's seems to me that the issue is with `Session.setDefault()`. When I console.log the `Session.course` variable right after the find, I get an empty array `[]`, maybe because there was no time to get the data from the server (or maybe not, because I'm developing with autopublish for now, I don't really know).

After I apply some of the filters (code not shown here), everything goes back to normal. This initialization only is the problem.

I've tried to call `Session.set()` inside `Template.courses.rendered()`, `Template.courses.created()`, `Template.courses.onRendered()`, `Template.courses.onCreated()` (yes, I was kinda desperate) but none of them worked.

Can someone please advise on that issue? Maybe I'm not trying the correct Meteor aproach, as I am a Meteor beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to use template subsciption. so you can send some terms for publication. example;

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function() {
  this.name = new reactiveVar("");

  this.autorun( () => {
    const terms = {
      name: this.name.get()
    };

    this.subscribe("Posts_list", terms);
  });
});

Template.foo.helpers({
  lists: function() {
    return Posts.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here. First thing is that your helper will run whenever either the result of `Courses.find().fetch()` or `Session.get('course')` changes, since both of them are [reactive data sources](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity). To avoid this, you can do

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  lists: function() {
    return Posts.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

If you want to set the session variable so that you can use it somewhere else, then you can use `Session.set` instead of `Session.setDefault`, because `Session.setDefault` will only assign value only is the session variable is not already available. But I don't know why you want to do that, since you can use `Posts.find().fetch()` where ever required instead of session variable. Both are reactive.

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  lists: function() {
    Session.set('course', Courses.find().fetch());
    return Session.get('course');
  }
});
```

If you want to assign the `course` session variable only for the first time when you get non-empty data then you might want to do something like this.

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  lists: function() {
    if (Courses.find().count() > 0) {
        Session.setDefault('course', Courses.find().fetch());
        return Session.get('course');
    } else {
        return [];
    }
});
```

If you can tell why you need the session variable, we might think of a different approach to solve the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm returning `Session.get('course')` in the `course helper` because later the user is going to filter the course dataset in order to find a course that matches the filters he specified. So, whenever he changes the filters in the form (which are just inputs and checkboxes), there is an event handler for them that changes the course Session variable accordingly (making a new find) and then the template is re-rendered.